# How to calculate phases and power factor of two loads in series

Tags: ac, homework

I have attempted the follow question by following the formula to sum up the cosine voltages below, but have had no success, would anyone be able to point me in the right direction? I tried graphing a solution but failed.
[image]

[image]

Comment: This has a Vector algebra solution (phasors)

Comment: Please edit your question and remove the shouting from the title. You might think it helps your question get attention and it does but not for the reasons you would want. Also, putting the word "question" in a question is superfluous. All of the questions are questions. The title should explain what the question is *about*.

Comment: What trig identities are you allowed to use?

Answer (score 1):

Describe each load as a complex impedance, then simply add them.

The common Ohm's law we usually see is actually a subset of the full law that applies when the impedance is purely resistive.  That simplifies the algebra since there are no complex numbers of phase angles involved.  However, Ohm's law does work with arbitrary impedances in general.

Likewise, two impedances in series present as the sum of the individual impedances.  Parallel impedances work the same as parallel resistances too.

The actual algebraic manipulations to perform computations on arbitrary impedances, as apposed to pure resistances, is significantly more complex, but the higher level equations are the same.